# How do i remove font awesome icons on my responsive navbar when in desktop version?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I remove font awesome icons on my responsive navbar when in desktop version? In my below project, everything is working just fine but the problem arises when the website is in desktop version since I do not want my font awesome icons to display there. In my CSS in their class created called (site-nav--icon) I have set display to none but it is still not working. Some help would be appreciated guys. Thanks in advance.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700');
    
    body{
        background: #F0F8EA;
        font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    }
    .container{
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    header{
        background: #E54B4B;
        color: #EBEBD3;
        padding: 1em 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    header::after{
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
    .logo{
        float: left;
        font-size: 1.65rem;
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    .site-nav{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        right: 0%;
        background: #464655;
        clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
        transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
        /* display: none; */
    }
    .site-nav--open{
        clip-path: circle(100%);
    }
    .site-nav ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .site-nav li{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
    }
    .site-nav li:last-child{
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    .site-nav a{
        color: #EBEBD3;
        display: block;
        padding: 2em 6em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .site-nav a:hover,
    .site-nav a:focus{
        background: #E4B363;
        color: #464655;
    }
    .site-nav--icon{
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        margin-right: 1em;
        width: 1.5em;
        text-align: right;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    }
    .menu-toggle{
        padding: 1em;
        position: absolute;
        top: .75em;
        right: .75em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .hamburger,
    .hamburger::before,
    .hamburger::after{
        content: '';
        display: block;
        background: #EBEBD3;
        height: 3px;
        width: 1.95em;
        border-radius: 3px;
        transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
    }
    .hamburger::before{
        transform: translateY(-7px);
    }
    .hamburger::after{
        transform: translateY(4px);
    }
    .open .hamburger{
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    .open .hamburger::before{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .open .hamburger::after{
        transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
    }
    @media (min-width: 1077px){
        .menu-toggle{
            display: none;
        }
        .site-nav{
            height: auto;
            position: relative;
            background: transparent;
            float: right;
            clip-path: initial;
        }
        .site-nav li{
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
        }
        .site-nav a{
            padding: 0;
            margin-left: 1.4em;
        }
        .site-nav a:hover,
        .site-nav a:focus{
            background: transparent;
        }
        .site-nav--icon{
            display: none;   
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
                    $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open');
                    $(this).toggleClass('open');
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="logo">SakaHapa</h1>
            <nav class="site-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home site-nav--icon"></i>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o site-nav--icon"></i>How It Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user-circle site-nav--icon"></i>Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-cart-plus site-nav--icon"></i>Purchases</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-eye site-nav--icon"></i>Popular</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-envelope site-nav--icon"></i>Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="menu-toggle">
                <div class="hamburger"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Replace `.site-nav--icon` with `i.site-nav--icon` in `@media (min-width: 1077px)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code without font awesome icons for desktop

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700');
    
    body{
        background: #F0F8EA;
        font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    }
    .container{
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    header{
        background: #E54B4B;
        color: #EBEBD3;
        padding: 1em 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    header::after{
        content: '';
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
    .logo{
        float: left;
        font-size: 1.65rem;
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    .site-nav{
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        right: 0%;
        background: #464655;
        clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
        transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
        /* display: none; */
    }
    .site-nav--open{
        clip-path: circle(100%);
    }
    .site-nav ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .site-nav li{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
    }
    .site-nav li:last-child{
        border-bottom: none;
    }
    .site-nav a{
        color: #EBEBD3;
        display: block;
        padding: 2em 6em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .site-nav a:hover,
    .site-nav a:focus{
        background: #E4B363;
        color: #464655;
    }
    .site-nav--icon{
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        margin-right: 1em;
        width: 1.5em;
        text-align: right;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    }
    .menu-toggle{
        padding: 1em;
        position: absolute;
        top: .75em;
        right: .75em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .hamburger,
    .hamburger::before,
    .hamburger::after{
        content: '';
        display: block;
        background: #EBEBD3;
        height: 3px;
        width: 1.95em;
        border-radius: 3px;
        transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
    }
    .hamburger::before{
        transform: translateY(-7px);
    }
    .hamburger::after{
        transform: translateY(4px);
    }
    .open .hamburger{
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    .open .hamburger::before{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .open .hamburger::after{
        transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
    }
    @media (min-width: 1077px){
        .menu-toggle{
            display: none;
        }
        .site-nav{
            height: auto;
            position: relative;
            background: transparent;
            float: right;
            clip-path: initial;
        }
        .site-nav li{
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
        }
        .site-nav a{
            padding: 0;
            margin-left: 1.4em;
        }
        .site-nav a:hover,
        .site-nav a:focus{
            background: transparent;
        }
        .site-nav li .fa{
            display: none;   
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
                    $('.site-nav').toggleClass('site-nav--open');
                    $(this).toggleClass('open');
                })
            })
        </script>

        <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="logo">SakaHapa</h1>
            <nav class="site-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home site-nav--icon"></i>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-question-circle-o site-nav--icon"></i>How It Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user-circle site-nav--icon"></i>Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-cart-plus site-nav--icon"></i>Purchases</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-eye site-nav--icon"></i>Popular</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-envelope site-nav--icon"></i>Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="menu-toggle">
                <div class="hamburger"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: Problem is in mobile device the icons disappear. I want them to show in mobile version but not to show in desktop version.

Comment: Yes try this code its will work for desktop only as the css is applied in min width so its will be hided on the screen that is above 1077px but below it it works.